# Reactjs - Handler not Fired by Event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm new to React and ES6 so this might be a simple issue I overlooked.

It seems that the onClick and onKeyDown events (or any event in that case) are not firing ( in this case the runSearch function):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'jquery';


var SearchBar = React.createClass({
runSearch: function(e) {
    console.log("Hello");
},
render: function() {

    return(
        <form action="#" >
            <div className="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                <input className="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" onKeyDown={this.runSearch} id="search-text" />
                <label className="mdl-textfield__label" htmlFor="search-text">Search</label>
            </div>
            <label className="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon" onClick={this.runSearch}>
                <i className="material-icons">
                    search
                </i>
            </label>
        </form>
    );
}
});

var MainContainer = React.createClass({
render : function(){
    return(
    <div className="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-drawer mdl-layout--fixed-header">
        <main className="main mdl-layout__content mdl-color--grey-100">
            <SearchBar />
        </main>
    </div>
    );
}
ReactDOM.render(<MainContainer />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Your example works fine https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/32373/

Comment: Yes, Thank you, it seems to be a problem with mdl, I added another component to my example with the mdl classes in my code. It works on my page when I take off the mdl-js-layout class.

Comment: If you're working with MDL and React I'd highly recommend the react-mdl package (https://github.com/tleunen/react-mdl). Compared to having to build all that flexibility yourself it's a lot easier to use that, it's actively developed and the owner is quite responsive.

Comment: I didn't know that exists, thanks a lot guys.

Comment: @Yuval check this also http://www.material-ui.com/#/